# Evaluating $\int_0^\infty\frac{x^\beta\xi^{1-\beta}}{t-\tau}\exp(-\frac{x^2+\xi^2}{4(t-\tau)})I_{\beta}(\frac{\xi x}{2(t-\tau)})d\xi $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Evaluate $$\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{x^{\beta }\xi ^{1-\beta }}{t-\tau }\exp \left ( -\frac{x^2+\xi ^2}{4(t-\tau )} \right )I_{\beta }\left ( \frac{\xi x}{2(t-\tau )} \right )d\xi $$
> where $I$ is the Modified Bessel function

**My attempt:**
$$
t^{\alpha }\int\limits_{0}^{t}\frac{1}{t^{2-2\beta }(t-\tau )^{\beta }}\exp \left ( -\frac{t^2}{4(t-\tau )} \right )\tau ^{-\alpha }d\tau =t^{\alpha }\frac{2\beta -1}{\Gamma \left ( \beta \right )}\int\limits_{t/4}^{\infty }\frac{z^{\beta -2}}{\left ( t-t^2/4z \right )^{\alpha }}e^{-z}dz=
$$
$$=\frac{2\beta -1}{\Gamma \left ( \beta \right )}\int\limits_{t/4}^{\infty }z^{\alpha +\beta -2}\left ( z-\frac{t}{4} \right )^{-\alpha }e^{-z}dz=\frac{2\beta -1}{\Gamma \left ( \beta \right )}\frac{t^{\beta /2-1}}{4^{\beta /2-1}}e^{-t/8}\mathrm{W}_{\alpha +\beta /2-1,1-\beta }\left ( \frac{t}{4} \right )$$
$\mathrm{W}$ $-$ Function Whittaker

*I came to a standstill... I have not been able to calculate this integral. Can anyone give me a hint?*

Comment: Start simplifying the notations.

Comment: as @ClaudeLeibovici already pointed out, the integral you gave is overly complicated in terms of notation. Writing the integral in a simpler way also (usually) makes it easier to see ways to solve it. So instead of asking for a solution of $$\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{x^{\beta }\xi ^{1-\beta }}{t-\tau }\exp \left ( -\frac{x^2+\xi ^2}{4(t-\tau )} \right )I_{\beta }\left ( \frac{\xi x}{2(t-\tau )} \right )d\xi$$ you should better ask for $$\int\limits_0^\infty\xi^{1-\beta }\exp \left ( -\alpha\xi ^2 \right )I_{\beta }\left ( \gamma\xi \right )\,\mathrm{d}\xi.$$ Just something for the next time

Comment: @RogerBernstein. One more simplification I forgot to do. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

*Given by a CAS* and using @RogerBernstein's notations

$$I=\int\limits_0^\infty\xi^{1-\beta }\,\exp \left ( -\alpha\,\xi ^2 \right )\,I_{\beta }\left ( \gamma\,\xi \right )\,\,d\xi$$

Provided that $$\Re(\beta )<2\land \Re(\gamma )\geq 0\land (\Im(\gamma )>0\lor \Re(\gamma )>0)\land
   \Re(\alpha )>0$$
$$I=\frac 1\gamma \,\,\left(\frac{2\alpha  }{\gamma }\right)^{\beta -1}\,\exp\Bigg[\frac{\gamma ^2}{4 \alpha }\Bigg]\,\,\Bigg[1-\frac{\Gamma \left(\beta ,\frac{\gamma ^2}{4 \alpha }\right)}{\Gamma (\beta )}  \Bigg]$$

Comment: Where did this result come from?

Comment: How did you get this integral value (answer)?

Comment: @Fk-91. I wrote it : a CAS made it.

Comment: Can I have a link to the source?

Comment: @Fk-91. Why don't you register at Wolfram Cloud ? It is free and you have all Mathematica

Comment: I'm not interested in the end result... I want to understand how we got there!